# Select all checked boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use select all checkboxes in the page by using this code:

```
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
```

In this code select all checkedbox. But if we select some checkboxes and give select all it select all. After we again unchecked selected all but previous checked box remain checked.

Comment: Instead of `$("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");` try `$("#selectall").attr("checked", false);`

Comment: $("#selectall").attr('checked', false);

Comment: Not `attr`, guys; `prop`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ooops, that was a bit schoolboy error! Thanks for the prop - pun intended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attr` part of `$('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);` is incorrect: The current checked state of a checkbox is represented by the `checked` *property*. The `checked` *attribute* is just [the *default* checked state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-checked) for the `input`, not its current checked state. (Just like the difference between the `value` property and the `value` attribute.)

To set the current state of the checkbox, use `prop`:

```js
$(function() {

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function() {
        $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function() {
        $("#selectall").prop("checked", $(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length);
    });
});
```

```html
<div><label><input type="checkbox" class="case"> One</label></div>
<div><label><input type="checkbox" class="case"> Two</label></div>
<div><label><input type="checkbox" class="case"> Three</label></div>
<div><label><input type="checkbox" class="case"> Four</label></div>
<div><label><input id="selectall" type="checkbox"> ALL</label></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```